# How to convert std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> > to std::vector<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference-wrapper

I have a local `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> >` and now I want to return a *real copy* of its elements (i.e `std::vector<T>`). Is there a better way than a loop?

Example:

```
std::vector<T> foobar() {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> > refsToLocals;
    /*
      do smth with refsToLocals
    */
    std::vector<T> copyOfLocals;
    for (auto local : refsToLocals)
        copyOfLocals.insert_back(local.get());
    return copyOfLocals;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems, the obvious approach is to just construct a `std::vector<T>` from a sequence from the `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`:

```
std::vector<T> foobar() {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> > refsToLocals;
    /* do smth with refsToLocals */
    return std::vector<T>(refsToLocals.begin(), refsToLocals.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::copy` this way:

```
std::copy(
    refsToLocals.begin(), 
    refsToLocals.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(copyOfLocals));
```

Be sure to use call `copyOfLocals.reserve(refsToLocals.size())`. It will minimize copies and heap-allocations.